# mysql over SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, windows, ssh, odbc, putty

I'm having an issue on both a win7 development machine, and on a windows 2008 production server with connecting to a remote Suse Linux server to mysql over SSH. I've followed the very simple instructions here.

http://realprogrammers.com/how_to/set_up_an_ssh_tunnel_with_putty.html

only on the last step, i'm trying to use the odbc connector that I downloaded from here.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

trying both localhost:3306 and 127.0.0.1:3306 doesn't seem to make a difference. I CAN log into the linux server in putty over ssh, and use the command line from the terminal to connect to mysql. My issue is that I need the windows server to be able to connect and query data from the mysql instance on the linux server. When I attempt to connect from the odbc connector it immediately pops up an error that root@localhost is denied with password=YES. I've checked my user table in mysql and root is set to allow login from any host, including localhost. Anyone have any other suggestions for getting this to work? It's quite urgent as we need to plan for a data synchronization of several gigs by this Saturday. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If root can login from any host, I think you don't need an SSH tunnel. did you try to connect directly, with MySQL Workbench for example?

Comment: for security reasons we have 3306 on the linux machine firewalled, this is why I need SSH to tunnel in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out... You have to run putty.exe as an administrator. Once I did that the connection worked just fine. Hopefully this saves someone a few hours of work down the road. Thanks to bfavaretto for his help.