# Using mysql via SSH (php)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, ssh

Try to connect to remote mysql via ssh2 and php.

```
$ssh_server='';
$ssh_port='';
$ssh_user='';
$ssh_password='';

$ssh_connection=ssh2_connect($ssh_server, $ssh_port);
$ssh_auth=ssh2_auth_password($ssh_connection, $ssh_user, $ssh_password);
$ssh_tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($ssh_connection, $ssh_server, $ssh_port);

$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_database = '';
$db_username = '';
$db_password = '';
$db_port = '3306';

$connection_mysql = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database, $db_port);
```

Tunnel is ok, but I see, that mysql use my local mysql DB, not remote via SSH. So, how can i use mysql via SSH?

OS windows with WAMP on it.

Comment: change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @Fred-ii- 127.0.0.1 it is like localhost. I try it, but I again trying connect to local db, not remote. I turnoff my local db, but it is not changed anyting.

Comment: Here are a few links you may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/23658689/1415724 --- http://stackoverflow.com/q/26880008/1415724 --- http://stackoverflow.com/q/9294653/1415724 --- http://stackoverflow.com/q/11061621/1415724 --- http://quintagroup.com/services/support/tutorials/mysql-windows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$ssh_connection = ssh2_connect($ssh_server, $ssh_port);
ssh2_auth_password($ssh_connection, $ssh_user, $ssh_password);
$query="SET CHARACTER SET utf8; use ${db_database}; ${query};";
$query=str_replace('"', '\'', stripslashes($query));
$ssh_query="ssh -L 3307:${ssh_server}:${ssh_port}; echo \"${query}\" | mysql -u ${db_username} -h ${db_hostname} --password=${db_password}";
$result=ssh2_exec($ssh_connection, $ssh_query);
```

Answer (score 1):

create private/public key and setup key authentication with ssh(aka passwordless authentication).

then run this code in your php script

```
shell_exec("ssh -f -L 3307:localhost:3306 myuser@10.0.0.1 sleep 10 >> logfile");
```

then create database connection like:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;port=3307", $username, $password);
```

Comment: it works if you install cygwin and append cygwin's bin folder to your path variable.